# Does $1 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(\ln(2))^n}{n!}$?

Tags: calculus

I wanted to know whether the following are true:

1. $$1 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(\ln(2))^n}{n!}$$
2. $$-1 = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^n$$

It seems like the second one is trivially false since the sum goes to infinity. 1. seems to be true at first glance, but if I expand it:

$$\ln(2) + \frac{(\ln(2))^2}{2} + \frac{(\ln(2))^3}{6}...$$ and factor out $\ln(2),$ it certainly seems to be greater than $1,$ making this one false as well.

Comment: Well, keep in mind that $\ln 2<1$.

Comment: As noted [here](https://youtu.be/XFDM1ip5HdU), the second equation is true in the $2$-adic norm on $\Bbb Q$. But as @Andrei's answer notes, you're absolutely right about the first equation being true (in the Euclidean norm on $\Bbb R$, of course).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the expansion of $e^x$:
$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
Plugging in $x=\ln 2$, you get:
$$e^{\ln 2}=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(\ln2)^n}{n!}$$
or
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(\ln2)^n}{n!}=e^{\ln 2}-1=2-1=1$$

Answer (score 4):

Now, $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty= \ln(2) + \frac{(\ln(2)^2}{2} + \frac{(\ln(2)^3}{6}+\cdots$$

But, $e^{x}=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}\cdots$
So,$$e^{\ln{x}}-1=\sum_{n=1}^\infty=2-1=1$$

Comment: Sorry for the late and same answer. A bit new to the community and am taking time to learn how to write the functions properly.